# How to restrict a domain on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The following rule is allowing only [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) domain to access the file list.txt

My question, how can I change the rule to restrict [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and allow other domain?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?google\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^list\.txt$ - [NC,F]
</IfModule>
```

I want the browser response to 404 but not denied response.

Comment: > `The following rule is allowing only www.google.com domain to access the file list.txt`. No that is just checking `HTTP_HOST` to `google.com` which will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test and see if this does what you want?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?google\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^list\.txt$ - [NC,R=404]
```

but this might be clearer:

```
<Files "list.txt">
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?google\.com$ [NC, R=404]
</Files>
```

I left out `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` for clarity.  If the module is not enabled, you might however prefer the server to not start opposed to just allow access.

Comment: The first solution you provide got an error when I apply to my .htaccess file.  When I remove the 'C' from [C, NC] and only left with [NC] then my browser is working again.

Comment: I guess chain is only valid for RewriteRule and not RewriterCond.  Updated answer with 2nd attempt.

Comment: Your last edit make it works! thank you my friend.